# Sample Pearson's R Covariance and Standard Deviation Missing $\frac{1}{n-1}$

Tags: statistics, covariance, correlation, standard-deviation

When calculating the Pearson's R for a sample set, the formula is given as:

$r_{xy} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar{x})(y_i - \bar{y})}{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar{x})^2}\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n (y_i - \bar{y})^2 }} $

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient#Naming_and_history)

But for a population we have the following formula:

$\rho_{x,y} = \frac{\text{cov}(X,Y)}{\sigma_x \sigma_y}$

And of course since we are using a sample (not a population), definitions of $\text{cov}(X,Y)$, $\sigma_x$ and $\sigma_y$ include a factor of $\frac{1}{n-1}$.

For example, sample covariance is defined:

$\text{cov}(X,Y) = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\bar{x}) (y_i - \bar{y})}{n-1}$

And a similar definition exists for $\sigma_x$ and $\sigma_y$.

I'm sure my algebra is missing a step somewhere.  My question is:

In the defenition of Pearson's R for a sample set, where did the $\frac{1}{n-1}$ go?

Comment: My understanding is this is only true for a population, but sample covariance has a factor of $\frac{1}{n-1}$.  Is this not true?  Perhaps I messed up my mathJax.

Comment: Note that the sample variance for $X_i$ is $\text{cov}(X,X)$, so even if you were to take the denominator as $n-1$, it would cancel out.

Comment: Also remember that what you are calling as "sample variance" with a denominator of ${n-1}$ is actually an unbiased estimator of the population variance. The sample variance calculated with the usual denominator $n$ is a biased estimator of population variance so the unbiased estimator may be preferred in certain contexts.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri this is actually where my question comes from.  I was trying to do some re-arranging and prove Bessel's correction, and I got stuck.  Probably the shortfall is in my algebra, but I'm still just a little stuck...

Comment: If you take sample covariance with denominator $n-1$, you also take the sample variance for either samples with denominator $n-1$ as you have observed. It cancels out when you take the ratio $\text{cov}(X,Y)/\sigma_x\sigma_y$...

Comment: @ShubhamJohri I know I'll feel very dumb soon... but aren't we dividing by sample standard deviation?  And in the sample standard deviation the $\frac{1}{n-1}$ is beneath the square root, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sample, if you define$$\text{cov}(X,Y)=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar x)(y_i-\bar y)}{n-1}$$then the sample variance for either samples is$$\sigma_x^2=\text{cov(X,X)}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar x)^2}{n-1}\\\sigma_y^2=\text{cov(Y,Y)}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i-\bar y)^2}{n-1}$$and thus$$\rho_{xy}=\frac{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar x)(y_i-\bar y)}{n-1}}{\sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar x)^2}{n-1}}\sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i-\bar y)^2}{n-1}}}$$and you can see the denominators still cancel off, giving the required expression for $r_{xy}$.

Comment: Ok I see it now. I actually wrote it this way on paper and didn’t see it. Duh, it’s quite simple. Thanks for indulging me. I’ll accept the answer.

Comment: You are welcome!